# How much secure the data is while using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am quite new to D3. I would like to know about the security of data while using d3. Once the data is displayed in the browser, will it be vanished once the browser is closed, or will it remain somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

All the data sent to a client browser are available for client. You must treat your data, as data that client can store and move around. This applies for everything that you sent over to a browser.

There is not such thing as secure d3.js data.

Comment: Thanks Baklazan! And how about the performance? Will D3 give much load to CPU and memory? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user5388364 It all depends how large your data it, but in my experience it works just fine even on smartphones.